# XMLSchemaImportWarning: Import of namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#'

Tags: django, saml-2.0, okta

I am trying to integrate [SAML2 Auth](https://github.com/fangli/django-saml2-auth) in the existing django project. However i have been getting this error continuously.

```
F:\finessevenv\lib\site-packages\saml2\xml\schema\__init__.py:18: XMLSchemaImportWarning: Import of namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#' from ['http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd'] failed: block access to remote resource http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd.
  return _XMLSchema(source, **kwargs)
F:\finessevenv\lib\site-packages\saml2\xml\schema\__init__.py:18: XMLSchemaImportWarning: Import of namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#' from ['http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmlenc-core-20021210/xenc-schema.xsd'] failed: block access to remote resource http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmlenc-core-20021210/xenc-schema.xsd.
  return _XMLSchema(source, **kwargs)
F:\finessevenv\lib\site-packages\xmlschema\validators\schema.py:1191: XMLSchemaImportWarning: Import of namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#' from ['http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd'] failed: block access to remote resource http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd.
  build=build,
F:\finessevenv\lib\site-packages\xmlschema\validators\schema.py:1191: XMLSchemaImportWarning: Import of namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#' from ['http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmlenc-core-20021210/xenc-schema.xsd'] failed: block access to remote resource http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmlenc-core-20021210/xenc-schema.xsd.
  build=build,
```

What could be the possible reason of this error and how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First off, try to use a more up-to-date version of the [django-saml2-auth](https://github.com/k6io/django-saml2-auth). I tried to maintain the original project out of necessity.

Second, have you installed `xmlsec1` binaries? If not, check out the [Windows binaries](https://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/download.html) built and published by Igor Zlatkovic on the project's website.

If none of the above fixed the issue, you probably have a configuration issue on your Django app or your Identity Provider app.